# How to convert dict value to a float

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

How to convert dict value to a float

```
dict1= {'CNN': '0.000002'}

s=dict1.values()
print (s)
print (type(s))
```

What I am getting is:

```
dict_values(['0.000002'])
<class 'dict_values'> # type, but need it to be float
```

but what I want is the float value as below:

```
 0.000002
 <class 'float'> # needed type
```

Comment: What's the result you want to get? A dict like `{'CNN': 0.00002}` or a single value like `s = 0.00002`?

Comment: Why are you using `values()` here? If you want to access the value of a single key, get it wth the square brackets syntax: `dict1["CNN"]`.

Comment: what I want is s = 0.00002, dict key is not constant it could be CNN or something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things here: firstly s is, in effect, an iterator over the dictionary values, not the values themselves. Secondly, once you have extracted the value, e.g. by a for loop.The good news is you can do this is one line:

```
print(float([x for x in s][0]))
```

Comment: Thanks, this one is working as float

Answer (score 7):

To modify your existing dictionary, you can iterate over a view and change the type of your values via a `for` loop.

This may be a more appropriate solution than converting to `float` each time you retrieve a value.

```
dict1 = {'CNN': '0.000002'}

for k, v in dict1.items():
    dict1[k] = float(v)

print(type(dict1['CNN']))

<class 'float'>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have many values in a dictionary you can put all values in a list an after that take values, but you need also to change type because your values are of type `strings` not `float`

```
dict1= {'CNN': '0.000002'}
values = [float(x) for x in list(dict1.values())]

for value in values:
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have stored the number as in a string. The use of quotes `dict1= {'CNN': '0.000002'}` makes it a string. Instead, assign it `dict1= {'CNN': 0.000002}

**Code:**

```
dict1= {'CNN': 0.000002}
s=dict1.values()
print (type(s))
for i in dict1.values():
    print (type(i))
```

**Output**:

```
<class 'dict_values'>
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: in his code value of `CNN` is `'0.00002'` of type string but in your code value of `CNN` is of type float

Comment: Please read the lines before the code. I suggested modifying dictionary first and then expressed the results desired.

Comment: ups, sorry, but if his dict come for example from http request ? how he will change it ?