# Changing certain elements of an array into floats in python

Tags: python, arrays

I currently have an array in my program, and each entry in the array is structured like this:

```
{'ts': '0', 'ph': '308.8', 'am': '-40.408'}
```

I want to change the numbers, which are currently stored as strings, to floats, but I'm clueless as to how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @komatiraju032: "...each entry *in the array*..."

Comment: @ScottHunter still likely not an array. List and array are different in Python

Comment: That is a pretty unhelpful dupe for this question @yatu.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50433921/9698684) not solve the *same* problem? @MarkMeyer

Comment: @yatu, yes, that's probably helpful — assuming the OP knows how to get each dictionary out of the list.

Comment: It just seemed like quite a clear dupe imo @MarkMeyer Its just a matter of adding another level of iteration. Quite possibly we'd also find dupes for list of dicts

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Sure, in that lists exist in Python and arrays do not.

Comment: @MarkMeyer. Given that OP hasn't posted a concrete issue beyond asking for someone to do the work for them, I'd vote to close the question regardless.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have no objection to closing the question and haven't voted to reopen. But I think if you are going to use the dupe hammer, it should be a good dupe for the next person that finds this. If it should be closed because it's a bad question, then vote with one of the other reasons.  Maybe quarantine just has me extra-grumpy.

Comment: @MarkMeyer. That sounds fair. I know I've been extra grumpy myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `dict` comprehension is what you are looking for

```
d= {'ts': '0', 'ph': '308.8', 'am': '-40.408'}
{k:float(v) for k,v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the values in-place you could loop over the elements in the list and then each key in the dictionary and change it:

```
l = [
    {'ts': '0', 'ph': '308.8', 'am': '-40.408'},
    {'ts': '10', 'ph': '100.8', 'am': '-2.0'}
]

for d in l:
    for k in d:
        d[k] = float(d[k])
```

The list `l` will then be:

```
[{'ts': 0.0, 'ph': 308.8, 'am': -40.408},
 {'ts': 10.0, 'ph': 100.8, 'am': -2.0}]
```

This assumes you want to change every value